# How to change all of the letters in an input file and print them to uppercase in an output file?

Tags: java, string

I need to ask the user for an input and output file and then print all of the letters in the input file to the outputfile all uppercase.

I've tried creating different variables and messing with char

```
 package programassignment;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;

 /**
 *
 * @author bambo
 */
public class ProgramAssignment {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the name of the input file?");
        String inputfilename=keyboard.nextLine();
        File f = new File(inputfilename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
        System.out.println("What is the name of the output file?");
        String outputfile=keyboard.nextLine();
         FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outputfile);
         PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

          int lineNumber=0;
          String upper = Letter.toUppercase();

            while(inputFile.hasNext());
         {   
             lineNumber++;
             int letterCount = 0;


         String line = inputFile.nextLine();
             if (line.length () != 0)
                letterCount++;

              for(int i=0; i< line.length(); i++)

              {
                 if(char.upper);
                 {
                    char.toUpperCase();
                 }


             }
```

I expect the input file to print all letters to uppercase in the output file

Comment: And what’s not working?

Comment: You read `line` but never do anything with it. You need to convert it to uppercase and write it to the file. `pw.println(line.toUpperCase());`.

Comment: This line has at least two things wrong:  ```if(char.upper);```  -- what is char supposed to be, and the if statement has a null controlled-clause.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains numerous defects, including not closing your output file; terminating your `while` body with a semicolon; counting lines for no discernable reason; not reading lines; not converting them to uppercase; and not writing to your output. I would use `try-with-resources` to ensure my resources are appropriately closed (namely the `Scanner` and output). I would use a `PrintStream`. That might look something like,

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is the name of the input file?");
String inputfilename = keyboard.nextLine();
File f = new File(inputfilename);
System.out.println("What is the name of the output file?");
String outputfile = keyboard.nextLine();
try (Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new File(outputfile))) {
    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        ps.println(inputFile.nextLine().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

> Okay, how could I have it work without using Try or Printstream?

You ***should*** be using `try`; but without it you would be responsible for closing your resources manually. As for using a `PrintWriter` instead of a `PrintStream`, make two calls to write; one for the line and the second for the line separator. Like,

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is the name of the input file?");
String inputfilename = keyboard.nextLine();
File f = new File(inputfilename);
System.out.println("What is the name of the output file?");
String outputfile = keyboard.nextLine();
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File(outputfile));
while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
    pw.write(inputFile.nextLine().toUpperCase());
    pw.write(System.lineSeparator());
}
pw.close();
inputFile.close();
```

Comment: How could I write this without using try or Prinstream but instead using a loop?

Comment: @Nitro this already uses one loop; adding another won't remove the need for a try.

Comment: Okay, how could I have it work without using Try or Printstream?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a couple of problems with your code, the main problem is that you never closed the Scanner or the File Writers. Here's my simple solution.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class StackOverflowHelp {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the name of the input file?");
        String inputfilename = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.close();
        try
        {
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(inputfilename));
            FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter("output.txt",true); 
            while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                String temp = fileScanner.nextLine();
                temp = temp.toUpperCase();
                fileOut.write(temp+"\n");
            }
            fileScanner.close();
            fileOut.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat Could you please explain this? I have always been told that it is very good practice to close the keyboard as soon as you are finished accepting input.